# Store maven credentials outside of settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3

I am working on my first time using maven to build a java project. This project requires a jar project that isn't hosted on the maven repository, so I am going to use S3 as a remote repository.

An issue that I appear to be running into is that the the S3 credentials must be stored in ~/.m2/settings.xml. I am not the only person working on this project, so ideally, I would like to keep those credentials in a per project basis, as opposed to a per user basis, as to ease the automation of checking out and building of the project. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven has a --settings option that allows specifying an alternate path to the settings.xml.

`mvn command --settings /path/to/settings.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Automation can be done within with a appropriate plugin `Config File Provider` which supports different settings.xml/toolchains.xm etc.

Apart from that create a git repository from your ${HOME}/.m2 including the settings.xml which stores the information you need so anyone else can clone this repository...

Comment: A little overkill for what I was thinking, will upvote anyways. Apparently, I just missed the above option in the maven help.

Comment: Not a overkill. I would never store credentials in my project.

Comment: Care to expand upon that one?

Comment: I store them in settings.xml ([of course encrypted](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)) and use the git approach which is very handy. Furthermore using the settings-security.xml which is on a usb-stick...So anyone else can do a clone of this repository or just copy it as a template and encrypt their passwords on their own.

Comment: But then you would still need to have your the git project containing the settings.xml be a git-submodule or use a build script of sorts to ensure the the two git projects are in sync, no?